# How to start processing after the user finishes typing with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an input element, where I want to show an autocomplete solution. I try to control the HTTP request's number with RxJS. I want to do: the HTTP request start only after 1 second of the user stop the typing.

I have this code:

```js
of(this.inputBox.nativeElement.value)
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    map((e: any) => this.inputBox.nativeElement.value),
    // wait 1 second to start
    debounceTime(1000),
    // if value is the same, ignore
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // start connection
    switchMap(term => this.autocompleteService.search({
      term: this.inputBox.nativeElement.value
    })),
  ).subscribe((result: AutocompleteResult[]) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

The problem is the `debounceTime(1000)` didn't wait to continue the pipe. The switchMap start immediately after every keyup event.

How can I wait 1 second after the user finishes typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your chain starts with `of(this.inputBox.nativeElement.value).pipe(take(1), ...)` so it looks like you're creating a new chain (with a new debounce timer) on every single key press.

Instead you should have just one chain and push values to its source:

```
const keyPress$ = new Subject();

...

keyPress$
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    ...
  )

...

keyPress$.next(this.inputBox.nativeElement.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a stream with `fromEvent`?

I didn't find necessary to use `distinctUntiChanged` as the `input` event only triggers when a change occurs (i.e. the user adds/removes stuff). So text going through the stream is always different.

```js
const {fromEvent} = rxjs;
const {debounceTime, map} = rxjs.operators;

const text$ =
  fromEvent(document.querySelector('input'), 'input')
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      map(ev => ev.target.value));

text$.subscribe(txt => {
  console.log(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```